# Which virtual method is executed in an inheritance hierarchy when intermediate classes skip the implementation?

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism, virtual, undefined-behavior

I'm sure that someone has asked this question before but I simply don't know what to search for. So I'm happy to remove this question as soon as someone points me to a similar one. I'm also happy to rename the questions if someone has a better suggestion :-)

I want to know if the following code is defined behavior by the standard or if this might be compiler/platform dependent:

```
struct A
{
    virtual void f()
    {
        std::cout << "A::f()" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B : public A
{
    // f() is not implemented here
};

struct C : public B
{
    virtual void f() override
    {
        B::f(); // call f() of direct base class although it is not implemented there
        std::cout << "C::f()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A* pA = new C();
    pA->f();
}
```

The output with Visual Studio 2017 and gcc 5.4.0 is:

```
A::f()
C::f()
```

Is it true that the compiler will search upwards in the hierarchy until it finds an implementation? Can you link to the C++ standard? I've tested it by making f() in A pure virtual and the linker nicely tells me that there is an unresolved symbol. Can I rely on that?

As I understand it using the scope operator like B::f() always calls the non-virtual version. So there is no polymorphism happening ever, is it?

**Edit**: The print statements where misleading, replaced "B::f()" with "C::f()".

Comment: This is called virtual or dynamic dispatch. Here's a link to wiki 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch 
There is also another interesting link:
http://condor.depaul.edu/ichu/csc447/notes/wk10/Dynamic2.htm

Comment: @AlexG I think that dynamic dispatch means the dynamic selection of the virtual method within a hierarchy which basically enables polymorphism. The lookup for the non-virtual base methods has nothing to do with that, I guess.

Comment: It's not a "non virtual base method". A non-virtual would be 'void foo()'. If it's marked as virtual, even though it belongs to the base class, then it is treated as virtual and creates a vftable. Now, if the child class does not override or "replace" the method of the base class, it will call the method in the base class. I think Vlad explained it better than I can in his answer.

Comment: You are right, but I'm missing the word for a call to a virtual method without invoking polymorphism. I guess it's just a "direkt method call" like I had when I wrote: B b; b.f(); // also simply calls A::f() without any polymorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dynamic type of the pointer

```
A* pA = new C();
```

is `C *`.

So the virtual function in the class C is called

```
struct C : public B
{
    virtual void f() override
    {
        B::f(); // call f() of direct base class although it is not implemented there
        std::cout << "B::f()" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

The class B does not redefine the virtual function of the base class A. So in this statement

```
        B::f(); // call f() of direct base class although it is not implemented there
```

the virtual function defined in the class A is called. That is the table of pointers to virtual functions of the class B contains the address of the function defined in the class A.

In this call

```
B::f();
```

there is access to the table of virtual functions of the class B and this table contains the address of the function definition in the class A because the function was not overriden in the class B.

From the C++ STandard (5.2.2 Function call)

> 1. ...If the selected function is non-virtual, or if the id-expression in the class member access expression is a qualified-id, that function
>      is called. Otherwise, its final overrider (10.3) in the dynamic type
>      of the object expression is called; such a call is referred to as a
>      virtual function call. [

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would you mind to go over my questions again and elaborate on each of them in more detail? (reference to C++ standard, scope operator,...)

Comment: 1) Calling B::f() inside of C::f() is basically the same as: B b; b.f(); right?
2) Can you point me to a section in the standard?

Comment: Many well known frameworks actually generate code similar to the OP's example. It is well-defined standard behavior AND practical. Basically in any OO GUI framework, the user code is supposed to call one base overload of an override inside the override.